# Windows 10 Mobile Release Preview : Sharing is not working

Tags: windows-10-mobile, nokia-lumia-620, sharing

The file sharing option is not working on my windows mobile release preview latest update. It's just showing preparing file and then come back without doing anything.

Os Build : 10.0.10586.318